# How to tell if a function is built-in or self-defined by its name?

Tags: matlab, function, built-in, function-declaration, call-graph

I generate a call graph of a complex MATLAB system, and I want to know which functions are built-in and mark them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think solutions based on `which` are better, for completeness, we should also consider the function [`exist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) for this. From the documentation:

> `exist name` returns the type of `name` as a number. This list describes the type associated with each value:
>
> - 0 — `name` does not exist or cannot be found for other reasons. For example, if `name` exists in a restricted folder to which MATLAB® does not have access, `exist` returns 0.
> - 1 — `name` is a variable in the workspace.
> - 2 — `name` is a file with extension `.m`, `.mlx`, or `.mlapp`, or name is the name of a file with a non-registered file extension (`.mat, .fig, .txt`).
> - 3 — `name` is a MEX-file on your MATLAB search path.
> - 4 — `name` is a loaded Simulink® model or a Simulink model or library file on your MATLAB search path.
> - 5 — `name` is a built-in MATLAB function. This does not include classes.
> - 6 — `name` is a P-code file on your MATLAB search path.
> - 7 — `name` is a folder.
> - 8 — `name` is a class. (exist returns 0 for Java classes if you start MATLAB with the `-nojvm` option.)

So when we try this on the examples shown [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249303/3372061):

```
>> exist eig
ans =
     5
>> exist solve
ans =
     2
>> exist nosuchfunction
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 5):

Whether a function is built-in or not is most easily seen by the [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) command.  For a given function name it displays the full path to the file that defines the function. For example, on my machine I see

```
>> which eig
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app/toolbox/matlab/matfun/eig)
>> which solve
/Users/robert/Documents/MATLAB/cvx/lib/@cvxprob/solve.m  % cvxprob method
>> which nosuchfunctionhere
'nosuchfunctionhere' not found.
```

telling me that `eig` is a built-in function, and `solve` a function that is part of the package cvx, and that `nosuchfunctionhere` is defined nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

MATLAB makes a distinction between "built-in functions" (i.e. no M-file or MEX-file exists, the code is built into the MATLAB executable) and other functions that are part of the MATLAB package but written as M-files or MEX-files.

As [Robert showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249303/7328782), the `which` function will tell you if a function is "built-in" or not, and it will give you a path.

For example, `eig` is a built-in function (the path given is a file containing the documentation):

```
>> p = which('eig')
p =
    'built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/matlab/matfun/@single/eig)'
```

`imshow` is not built-in, but part of the core MATLAB toolbox:

```
>> p=which('imshow')
p =
    '/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/matlab/images/imshow.m'
```

`imdilate` is a function that comes with the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
>> p = which('imdilate')
p =
    '/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/images/images/imdilate.m'
```

and `prettyplot` is a function I wrote myself:

```
>> p = which('prettyplot')
p =
    '/Users/cris/matlab/toolbox/cris/prettyplot.m'
```

To distinguish between these 4 cases, first check to see if the returned string begins with "built-in", then check to see if it contains `fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab')`, indicating it is part of the core MATLAB toolbox, then check to see if it contains `fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox')`, indicating it is part of another official toolbox:

```matlab
function_name = 'eig';
p = which(function_name);
if startsWith(p,'built-in')
   disp('built-in')
elseif contains(p,fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab'))
   disp('part of core MATLAB toolbox')
elseif contains(p,fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox'))
   disp('part of an official MATLAB toolbox')
else
   disp('not an official MATLAB function')
end
```

---

However, do note that some functions could be overloaded! And if you're examining your source code to check which functions are being used, you need to know the types of the arguments passed. For example:

```
>> which -all eig
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/matlab/matfun/@single/eig)  % single method
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/matlab/matfun/@double/eig)  % double method
/Users/cris/newdip/target/dip/share/DIPimage/@dip_image/eig.m                 % dip_image method
```

Here you can see that there are three `eig` functions, one is used if its input argument is of type `single`, one if it is `double`, and one if it is `dip_image` (a custom class). Depending on the input, the function `eig` used is built-in or a 3rd party function.

The sad part is, you won't know which one is used until you run your code. You can manually check what values the input variables have, sometimes it is clear. But this is not always the case, the type might depend on data outside of the function you're examining.

So, the best way to collect a list of functions your program uses is to run the profiler.

Another alternative: the MATLAB Compiler (a separate product) will collect all source M-files your function uses, and package them together into a single distributable package.

Comment: One doesn't have to run the program/profiler - check out [`matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('filename.m')`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html). You could then perform the `exist`/`which` test on each of the returned files.

Answer (score 1):

Just type  open followed by the function name in command  window

```
open function_name
```

And `function_name` will be displayed into editor, you might see **Mathwork copyright** inside it if it's a build in function otherwise it's not

This is how the copyright looks

```
%   Copyright 1993-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
```